# Find $y$ in $y^4-6y^3+14y^2-20y+8=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, quartics

> Find $y$ in $$\displaystyle y \cdot \frac{6-y}{y+1}\bigg(\frac{6-y}{y+1}+y\bigg) = 8$$

Solution I tried  $y(6-y)(6+y^2)=8(y+1)^2$

$(6y-y^2)(6+y^2)=8(y^2+2y+1)$

$(36y+6y^3-6y^2-y^4)=8y^2+16y+8$

$y^4-6y^3+14y^2-20y+8=0$

Help me how to solve it after that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start this way. Let $z=\cfrac {6-y}{y+1}$

Then, clearing fractions $yz=6-y-z$.

You also have $yz(y+z)=8$ so letting $t=y+z$ you get the quadratic $(6-t)t=8$ which you can solve.

Then you have two values of $t$ and each yields a quadratic for $y$.

Answer (score 2):

It factorises as 
$$(y^2-4y+2)(y^2-2y+4)=0,$$
so the solutions are $y=2\pm\sqrt{2}, 1\pm i\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yes, but how can you find the factorisation under exam conditions?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That's not the question. Indeed it might be hard to spot that it factorises at all under exam conditions. A different approach is then preferable, as in Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1):

make the Ansatz $$(y^2+ay+b)(y^2+cy+d)=y^4-6y^3+14y^2-20y+8$$
for your control it is
$$(2-4y+y^2)(4-2y+y^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

For all real $k$ we have:
$$y^4-6y^3+14y^2-20y+8=(y^2-3y+k)^2-9y^2-2ky^2+6ky-k^2+14y^2-20y+8=$$
$$=(y^2-3y+k)^2-((2k-5)y^2-(6k-20)y+k^2-8)=$$
$$=(y^2-3k+3)^2-(y^2+2y+1)^2=(y^2-3y+3)^2-(y+1)^2=(y^2-4y+2)(y^2-2y+4).$$
Can you end it now?